# Does foreach execute the query only once?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of items and a LINQ query over them. Now, with LINQ's deferred execution, would a subsequent foreach loop execute the query only once or for each turn in the loop?

Given this example (Taken from [Introduction to LINQ Queries (C#), on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397906.aspx))

```
    // The Three Parts of a LINQ Query: 
    //  1. Data source. 
    int[] numbers = new int[7] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

    // 2. Query creation. 
    // numQuery is an IEnumerable<int> 
    var numQuery =
        from num in numbers
        where (num % 2) == 0
        select num;

    // 3. Query execution. 
    foreach (int num in numQuery)
    {
        Console.Write("{0,1} ", num);
    }
```

Or, in other words, **would there be any difference if I had**:

```
    foreach (int num in numQuery.ToList())
```

And, would it matter, if the underlying data is not in an array, but in a Database?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Now, with LINQ's deferred execution, would a subsequent foreach loop execute the query only once or for each turn in the loop?

Yes, once for the loop. Actually, it may execute the query less than once - you could abort the looping part way through and the `(num % 2) == 0` test wouldn't be performed on any remaining items.

> Or, in other words, would there be any difference if I had:

```
foreach (int num in numQuery.ToList())
```

Two differences:

1. In the case above, `ToList()` wastes time and memory, because it first does the same thing as the initial `foreach`, builds a list from it, and then `foreach`s that list. The differences will be somewhere between trivial and preventing the code from ever working, depending on the size of the results.
2. However, in the case where you are going to *repeatedly* do `foreach` on the same results, or otherwise use it repeatedly, the then while the `foreach` only runs the query once, the next `foreach` runs it again. If the query is expensive, then the `ToList()` approach (and storing that list) can be a massive saving.

Comment: Yes once. Perhaps even less than a whole execution of the query, as the edit above explains.

Answer (score 10):

No, it makes no difference. The `in` expression is evaluated once. More specifically, the `foreach` construct invokes the `GetEnumerator()` method on the `in` expression and repeatedly calls `MoveNext()` and accesses the `Current` property in order to traverse the `IEnumerable`.

OTOH, calling `ToList()` is redundant. You shouldn't bother calling it.

If the input is a database, the situation is slightly different, since LINQ outputs `IQueryable`, but I'm pretty sure that `foreach` still treats it as an `IEnumerable` (which `IQueryable` inherits).

Comment: ... and that's why an exception is thrown upon attempting to change the collection one's `foreach`-ing through.

Comment: @Alex or strictly, why it *may* be thrown. The rules for `foreach` don't promise that modification will be allowed, but collections are free to allow it, and sometimes must (those which are designed for concurrent use would be stymied if they had to prohibit simultaneous changes from other threads).

Answer (score 2):

As written, each iteration of the loop would do exactly as much work as it needed to fetch the next result. So the answer would technically be "none of the above". The query would execute "in pieces".

If you use `ToList()` or any other materialization method (`ToArray()` etc) then the query will be evaluated once *on the spot* and subsequent operations (such as iterating over the results) will simply work on a "dumb" list.

If `numbers` were an `IQueryable` instead of an `IEnumerable` -- as it would likely be in a database scenario -- then the above is still close to the truth although not a perfectly accurate description. In particular, on the first attempt to materialize a result the queryable provider would talk to the database and produce a result set; then, rows from this result set would be pulled on each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The linq query will be executed when it is enumerated (either as the result of a `.ToList()` call or doing a `foreach` over the results.

If you are enumerating the results of the linq query twice, both times will cause it to query the data source (in your example, enumerating the collection) as it is itself only returning an `IEnumerable`. However, depending on the linq query, it may not always enumerate the entire collection (e.g `.Any()` and `.Single()` will stop on the first object or the first matching object if there is a `.Where()`).

The implementation details of a linq provider may differ so the usual behaviour when the data source is a database is to call `.ToList()` straight away to `cache` the results of the query & also ensure that the query (in the case of EF, L2S or NHibernate) is *executed once there and then* rather than when the collection is enumerated at some point later in the code and to prevent the query being executed multiple times if the results are enumerated multiple times.