# removing specific string values from a List

Tags: c#, list

I have a List of string values and and some of the values contains xxx or XXX in front.

```
xxxRed
xxxYellow
xxxxCareful with that axe Eugene!
xxxxxxdedicum aceasta frumoasa Melodia
xxxxLeaders
xxxxWorking Around - titles
XXXXXNothing To Fear
xxxxAvoiding standards
xxxFirst Aid

List<string> lstTitles = new List<string>();
```

This is what I have tried

```
for (int i=0; i < lstTitles.Count; i++)
            {
                string title = lstTitles[i].ToLower().Trim();
                if (title[0] == 'x')
                {
                    lstTitles.Remove(lstTitles[i]);

                }
            }
```

Problem I have is that only some of the values are removed but not all of them.

Is there perhaps a better way of removing these values?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [RemoveAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) method

```
lstTitles.RemoveAll(s => s[0] == 'x' || s[0] == 'X');
```

and you may want to use `StartsWith` instead of comparing first char.

```
lstTitles.RemoveAll(s => s.StartsWith("x",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: `|| s[0] == 'X'`... also, would fail if a string item is null or empty.

Comment: Does not handle the case, and OP mentionned wants to remove items starting with 'xxx', not 'x' ;)

Comment: @l4V, actually, OP's code is wrong, because, it would remove 'Xavier' from the list. And i'm sure he doesn't want that

Answer (score 3):

> Problem I have is that Only some of the values are removed but not all of them.

Because you're skipping items. When you call `Remove()`, the next item will be at index `i`, but you'll increase `i` in the next loop.

It can be solved by iterating over a copy of the list, and removing unwanted items in the original:

```
foreach (var item in lstTitles.ToList())
{
    if (item.StartsWith("x", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        lstTitles.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

Though this involves creating a copy of the list, which isn't really useful, as well as calling `Remove()` which itself is far from performant.

So you could invert your for-loop, to remove the last items first which doesn't change the indexing for unprocessed items:

```
for (int i = lstTitles.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
    if (lstTitles[i].StartsWith("x", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        lstTitles.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

But as @I4V points out, all of this logic already is in `List<T>.RemoveAll()`, which is nicer to read and probably optimized for some edge cases, so there's little use to hand-code it again.

Comment: This will throw an error because the collection has been modified while in a foreach loop.

Comment: @Sean no it doesn't, because I call `.ToList()`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, missed that, my bad =]

Comment: So in every iteration you're creating a new collection from the old. That's really inefficient.

Comment: @TimSchmelter that is [not how `foreach()` works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250561/does-foreach-execute-the-query-only-once).

Comment: @CodeCaster: Yes i know. So there's no reason to use a `foreach` in this case. Instead you should use a backwards `for`-loop or `RemoveAll`(best).

Comment: @TimSchmelter then don't say "in every iteration". :-) But agreed, updated.

Answer (score 2):

That's because your skipping values.

Suppose your list contains ['xVal1', 'xVal2', 'val3', 'xVal4', 'val5']. At first your `i` is 0, and you look at list[0], which is 'xVal1', so you remove it.

*Now* your list contains ['xVal2', 'val3', 'xVal4', 'val5'], and your `i` is 1. So you look at list[1] which is 'val3'. You ignored xVal2 !

You can start at the back of the list and go to the front, although you will still have a potential bug in case there are identical values you remove.

A shorter way would be to use LINQ:

```
var newList = lstTitles.Where(title=>!title.StartsWith('xxx'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `ToLower` you should use the overload of `StartsWith` which allows to pass a `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`.

Then use `List.RemoveAll` which is the most readable, most efficient and shortest approach:

```
lstTitles.RemoveAll(s => s.TrimStart().StartsWith("x", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/oWS3fI)

Answer (score 2):

I think, you'd better just create a new list this way

```
list = list
    .Where(i => ! i.StartsWith("xxx", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    .ToList();
```

It would have a O(n) complexity whereas, trying to remove then 1 by 1 would be in O(n^2).

Comment: Why would looping over a list once have a complexity of > O(n)?

Comment: I was refering to @CodeCaster's code which uses list.Remove(string) which is by it self in O(n). So if you loop through the list, and for some items, you use list.Remove(string), you could have a combined complexity of O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

This could work also :

```
list.RemoveAll(i => i.StartsWith("xxx", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Handles all cases and without a second list.